# Can I use multiple qualifiers in an image name? (scale + DeviceFamily)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a different image that needs to show up depending on whether the device family is desktop or mobile. There is scant documentation about this, but essentially it seems like the way to do it is to use it as a qualifier.

So I tried this:
`Sketch1.DeviceFamily-Desktop.scale-100.png`
But no cigar

However, if I specifiy no scale, it seems to be working:
`Sketch1.DeviceFamily-Desktop.scale-100.png`

Is there a way to specify two qualifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate multiple qualifiers in a file name with an underscore or set them in a folder structure rather than a flat file.

```
Sketch1.DeviceFamily-Desktop_scale-100.png
```

or

```
DeviceFamily-Desktop/scale-100/sketch1.png
```

See [How to name resources using qualifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324(v=win.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try separating them with an underscore "_" instead of another dot "."

Sketch1.DeviceFamily-Desktop_Scale-100.png